# Rollback on insert error from C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am inserting a series of rows with roll back option if any error occurs.

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...);
    INSERT INTO myTable (myColumns ...) VALUES (myValues ...);


COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack 

END CATCH
```

in C#, i am inserting rows in for loop. Is it possible to attain the same feature here also?

```
foreach(string lst in str[])
{
    //insert query
    dbl.ExecSqlNonQuery("sp_tbltest", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

if any error occurs in loop, all rows shoud roll back.

Comment: You should investigate how `SET XACT_ABORT ON` would change your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
    {            
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //// create the connection
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                //// open the connection
                connection1.Open();

                foreach(string lst in str[])
                {
                     //insert query
                     connection1.ExecSqlNonQuery("sp_tbltest", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }                    
            }

            scope.Complete();

        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        scope.Rollback();
    }
```

Comment: Who is `transaction`? Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 
you can commit and rollback on error using SqlTransaction

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx